# I was hoping there was a way that I could paint the glass into opaque gloss black glass, both sides

Tags: paint, glass

[image: Glass]Hello,  I’m in Los Angeles, California, 91604.  I’m a retired senior, and I just bought this house but I can’t stand the glass in the doors. It looks like the entrance to a church. I was hoping there was a way that I could turn the glass into opaque gloss black glass, both sides meaning the indoor side and the outdoor side. I had thought about replacing the glass, but that might damage the woodwork to pry it off just to get the glass out plus it would be very expensive if I can even find someone who could do it.  I just did a quick Google search and found you and thought I would ask you to please look at the attached picture of my doors and let me know what you think can be done . Of course, then I would have to find someone who can do it which is another challenge. Please advise. Thank you.
Jerry

Comment: I strongly suggest living with it for a few months before doing anything (a) irreversible that (b) really won't look good. If you must cover these, I would suggest finding a way to mount a panel over them, reversibly... But I really, really think you'll regret doing so.

Comment: It might look like a church now, but if you paint them black it will look like a crypt, or a morgue. If you don't like the dark wood, replace them with something less 'ecclesiastic' -  light wood, or even uPVC, but whatever you do, don't lose all the windows or the hallway will go from airy to gloomy.

Answer (score 4):

An out of the box idea: automobile window tint comes in different percentages of light transmission. (This does require a smooth glass surface.)

- diy
- reversible if you hate it

Comment: You beat me to it! Amazon actually has a *blackout* window tint made for residential/commercial windows that looks like it would solve this issue with the added benefit of being cheap, easy, reversible like you mentioned.

Comment: +1, was going to suggest window tint film. It's easy to apply, has no risk of smearing paint all over the wood, is removable, and looks nice.

Comment: If you use one-way mirror film, it'll look nothing like a church OR a crypt!

Answer (score 2):

Most doors and windows are designed so the glass can be replaced, without damaging anything. Contact a glazier and ask for quotes.

People who buy these do so because they like these features. It would be a backward step to remove them. I do wonder why you bought it.

Another option is that you could sell the entire joinery and replace it with what you like.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring "is it a good idea?" you **can** paint them black.

Paint only one side. Whichever side you're like to look better, paint the other one. Glass backed by paint looks better than paint on the surface of glass. Getting a good looking gloss coat on the painted side will be a challenge, and then it's subject to scratches as life goes on around it.

Black painted glass windows were a common feature of older barns where I grew up, as they were built with windows and then experience and research showed that the light from the windows was damaging the stored hay, so they were blacked out. Newer barns were built without windows in the hay mow section. They were typically painted from the inside, and looked perfectly glossy black from the outside.

A perfect look from both sides is achievable by replacing the glass with black glass, or with a sandwich of clear glass, both sheets painted black on the inner side. Placing a film between two sheets of glass can also work - could be black, could be aluminum foil for a different blacked-out look. Any competent glazier should be able to replace the glass without damage.